# How to generate activation code for c program?

Tags: c, linux, installation

i want to sell one program to customer， but I want to make one program can run at one server with only one lisence code, if customer want to run the program at other servers, he needs to buy more activation codes.

so is there a good method to generate activation code? i imagine that it will be related with one password and server mac-address

BTW: I just need one easy method, because my customer is not technology man

Comment: Have you done any research on the subject? I imagine this belongs more in programmers, but you'd probably get the same kind of questions there.

Comment: It's easy to spoof a MAC address: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_spoofing

Comment: Well you could make the program gather some unique information (MAC, Hardware information) from the host system and then generate a hash string from the information. After that you can generate the actual "registration / serial keys" for that particular hash. This system has nasty downsides. For example unique hash and serial key does not match after hardware upgrade so there  must be some system to back that up. Remember that almost everything can be reverse engineered and it is extremely hard to create bulletproof solution.

Comment: Athabaska: MAC is VERY easily spoofable.

Comment: @Dhaivat Pandya thats why I mentioned other `Hardware information` too. Maybe I was a bit unclear in my expression in the earlier comment.. Even some motherboards allows to change the MAC address directly from the bios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are well-established solutions for [product activation][2], and they already deal with the issues you need to think about, including:

- Securely activating licenses on systems without an Internet connection
- Allowing users to securely relocate licenses
- Allowing installation on virtual systems without enabling unlimited copying
- When a user's system crashes, how you get their license up again on another system.
- Protecting against various hacking attacks
- What to use for locking? And as Alex says, the MAC address is not a good choice, even if it has been a common one. A combination of systems parameter is best, but then how do you deal gracefully with a user who does a minor system upgrade?
- Secure trial licenses, whether time-limited, function-limited, or indeed both.
- Configuring product features
- Licensing upgrades...
  ....and much more.

Answer (score 2):

I can give you a rough idea, but, it isn't very easy.

Have a server running, and, at the start of your program, make it query your server with an activation code and a generated hash code (that is unique to each compile of the program) and have your server check if the combination has been queried before.

Comment: So now this server has to be on the internet and have access to the outside world (maybe not good or might not matter); second, easy to spoof a response and copy the program; finally hard to update since you now have N deliverables per update (1 per instance) and a complex error prone license business logic to maintain.

Comment: Andrew White: I agree with all your points :) I just cannot think of a better way.

Comment: fair enough; the points where not to criticize your answer but rather to highlight possible limitations that were not obvious in the answer.

Comment: @why: "the" mac, are you assuming there is only per computer?

Answer (score 1):

There is no perfect way to do this since virtualization can basically emulate any environment to amazing detail. License files, signed executables, and remote license servers are all options but are such a strain on your customer. I recommend you form a license agreement with your customer and *trust* them. There is no reason that you couldn't adopt some sort of periodic audit but in the end it comes down to a matter of trust vs convenience.

Comment: yeah I think it completely depends on your customer and business model. For many enterprise tools, licensing issues are a given and not a big deal.

Comment: And if you are selling into an enterprise environment find out what license managers they are already using and use *that* one yourself. Admins *hate* having to run a dozen different license managers.